# Fourier expansion and transform - what about the phase of the waves that i am adding?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, fourier-transform

Say we have a wave on the surface of the water and we want to describe it as a sum of other waves. So we use Fourier expansion to add waves of different wavelengths. For simplicity, say we have to just add two waves in order to get the mathematical description of the wave we have. If we add the two waves, the resulting wave will largely depend on the phase difference of the waves we added. For example, if the two waves are sinusoidal , if they have zero phase difference they will add up to a different wave than if they had a phase difference of π.
So, how do we consider the phase of each wave that we add up in the Fourier expansion and Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

The most mathematically general way to write a Fourier expansion is to use complex waves with complex amplitudes. In this case the phase of the waves is represented by the complex phase of the amplitude. You can see this if you write the amplitude in polar form. Here's how it looks for your two-component wave example:

$$
f(\mathbf x,t)
= z_1 e^{\mathbf k_1 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_1 t}
+  z_2 e^{\mathbf k_2 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_2 t}
= r_1 e^{\phi_1} e^{\mathbf k_1 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_1 t}
+  r_2 e^{\phi_2} e^{\mathbf k_2 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_2 t}
$$
$$
f(\mathbf x,t)
= r_1 e^{\mathbf k_1 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_1 t + \phi_1}
+  r_2 e^{\mathbf k_2 \centerdot \mathbf x - \omega_2 t + \phi_2}
$$

Of course, it doesn't make that much sense to think of water waves in terms of complex numbers, so we could restrict $f$ to the real numbers by adding the complex conjugate of those components.

If you want to write a Fourier series with only real functions, then the phase of the wave comes from the component functions themselves. If you expand with sine and cosine terms, you can get any phase from linear combinations of sines and cosines. For example, for a given wave component with wavevector $\mathbf k$ and phase $\phi$,

$$
 \cos(\mathbf k \centerdot \mathbf x + \phi)
 = \cos \phi \cos(\mathbf k \centerdot \mathbf x)
   - \sin \phi \sin(\mathbf k \centerdot \mathbf x)
$$

In this case, a Fourier series of real functions carries its phase information in the relative amplitudes of its sine components versus its cosine components.

Comment: So you are saying that in the Fourier transform of f(x,t) where we have the integral of y(x,t)*exp[kx]*dk (where y(x,t) is the fourier transform of f(x,t) ) , the phase of each wave that we add is included in y(x,t)?

Comment: First off, if y is the space transform of f, it would depend on k instead of x: i.e. y(k,t). Other than that, yes, y would have complex values, and the complex phase of the number y(k,t) determines the phase of the component wave with wavenumber k.